# Save and Update in the same @Transaction JPA

Tags: jpa, spring-transactions

I have a list of Sales products, but the things is: 
The costumer can return some products after two or three days. I gotta perform this operation in my system too.

Therefore, I update the sale's products by sending a list to my REST service build using Spring Boot and Spring Data: One example of the list would be

```
Sale:
 Products:
    0: 
      id: null
      description: 'Shirt'
      quantity: 2
      removed: true
    1:
      id: 1
      description: 'Shirt'
      quantity: 1
      removed: false
```

Things is: How can I update the product whose ID is not null and save the one whose ID is null in the same transaction? 
When I try to do that, I received the error: Detached entity, persist it before flushing it.
My method has the @Transaction from *org.springframework.transaction.annotation;*
I could first delete every product and then insert the list all over, but it seems to be logically wrong

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Without any information about what your existing codes look like , I could only give you the most fundamental solution which assume you are using the fundamental API which is `EntityManger` directly. The codes look some likes:

```java
@Service
public class ProductProssor {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManger em;


    @Transactional
    public void process(List<ProductDTO> productDTOs){

        for(ProductDTO productDTO : productDTOs){
            process(productDTO);
        }
    }


    private void process(ProductDTO productDTO){

        if(productDTO.getId() == null){
            Product product = new Product();
            //configure the product state from productDTO
            ....

            em.persist(product);
        }else{
            Product product = em.find(Product.class, productDTO.getId());
            if(product == null){
                throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Product with this ID %s cannot be found.", productDTO.getId()));
            }

            //update your product state from productDTO
           .....
        }

    }

}
```

`ProductDTO` is the object represents the payload of the REST API request. Also, the whole process is in one transaction which means if any of the ProductDTO throw exception will cause all things to rollback.

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54149027/339637) to prevent OOM if you have to process a lot of product.